# Science fiction book about tree people

Tags: story-identification, books

It had something to do with humans that had evolved into bird/lizard-like people that were taller and lived in the trees. Also standard humans that were considered short and strong by the bird people, I think they called the standard humans dwarves.

I read it during the 90s when I was in middle school so I don't know if it's a kids book or an adult book. The book was in English, if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: It sounds a little like "The Integral Trees" (and sequels) by Larry Niven. The environment was very low-gravity, and most of the people we meet are very tall and skinny (but not lizard- or bird-like). There's a character who's referred to as a dwarf who is able to fit into a spacesuit that was obviously designed for a "standard human".

Comment: @user888379 — It looks like we had the same idea. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Gaultheria I like your answer just fine.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259035/huge-trees-in-an-air-belt-in-space (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 17):

## Larry Niven, [*The Integral Trees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees) (1984) and [*The Smoke Ring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smoke_Ring_(novel)) (1987)

Humans have colonized a free-fall ("zero gravity") biosphere orbiting a neutron star.  Some of the humans live in pseudogravity at the ends of enormous trees larger than skyscrapers, while others inhabit free-floating structures.  In the absence of strong planetbound gravity, these colonists grow taller than their terrestrial ancestors.  While their hands are still fully-functional, they can also use their elongated toes for holding onto tools and anchor points; in a way, they can "fly" and "perch" like birds.  Only dwarves (the very shortest of the colonists) can use the advanced equipment built into the old spacesuits .

You can borrow [*The Integral Trees*](https://archive.org/search.php?query=niven%20integral%20trees) and [*The Smoke Ring*](https://archive.org/search.php?query=niven%20smoke%20ring) as e-books from [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/about/).

[image: Cover: The Integral Trees]
[image: Cover: The Smoke Ring]