# Huge trees in an "air belt" in space

Tags: story-identification, space

I read this decades ago.

The idea that there was in space, around some star, an "air" belt, like an asteroid belt, with enough atmosphere that people could live there without special life-support. Maybe there were also rocks and "dirty ice" blocks, but I am not sure. What definitely was there are **huge** trees, and people mostly have settled on these trees.

Since everything was rotating, Coriolis forces dominated the dynamics, so people who kept "flying" from one tree to another had developed new reflexes very unusual to us.

I do not remember much about the story itself.

I vaguely remember a very dangerous trip to a stable [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point) (due to the presence of a planet, probably just a planetoid, sharing the orbit of the air and the trees), but I don't remember **why** the trip was attempted. Possibly to recover some stuff, since in the story vagrant stuff would tend to drift towards stable Lagrange points (I believe the author did not have a very clear understanding of stable Lagrange points but this is irrelevant).

It was either a rather short novel, perhaps a rather long novella, I am not sure.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is Niven's [*The Integral Trees*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1709) (1984), or possibly its sequel [*The Smoke Ring*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47458) (1987).  The stories are set in orbit around a neutron star that has a zone of atmosphere in orbit around it at the habitable temperature of liquid water.  (There is another, yellow, star that is the binary companion of the neutron star that provides light for photosynthesis, but the smoke ring orbits close to the neutron star.)

People live on the titular kilometres-long trees, which are named after the shape of an integral sign (∫) although as described in the story they are more angular, like 2 hockey sticks taped butt-ends-together.  The trees are tidally oriented perpendicular to their orbital motion, and the winds generated by the differing orbital speeds between the top and bottom drag the foliage into "tufts" at each end of the tree.  (Except for the tufts, where it is possible to pull moisture out of the moving air, the trees are mostly barren.)

The "satellite" you're talking about is actually Goldblatt's World, a gas giant that is the source of the atmosphere in the smoke ring.  Reviewing the plot I believe you're actually recalling the second book (*The Smoke Ring*) which has Kendy send the people on Citizen's Tree to visit "The Admiralty" who have colonized "The Clump", a semi-stable grouping of ponds and vegetation that orbits at Goldblatt's World's L4 point.

Comment: Yes. That perfectly fits my memories. Indeed now I remember "the interplay between gravity and the winds generated by the differing orbital speeds between the top and bottom." That was fast ! Probably the first one, it didn't feel like a sequel missing the first book. Or possibly I read both, in the right order. That was long ago.....

Comment: At one point, they were sold in a single volume.

Comment: The Smoke Ring was gas torus from the gas giant, Goldblatt's world, known as "Gold" to the inhabitants, held and compressed by tides from a neutron star, and illuminated by the binary companion of the neutron star.  Trust me, Larry Niven had the orbital mechanics and L4/L5 points right.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The setting did seem very well-thought-out, and very memorable.  I was even willing to accept that the smoke ring atmosphere might be stable, but given the normal composition of a gas giant where did all the oxygen come from?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I read the wiki pages on "The Integral trees" and "The Smoke Ring" and Lagrange point is only mentioned in the second one, so I probably read both. A gas giant, hmmm. My objections about L4/L5 dynamics is that is is hardly a "normal" potential well like a planet, just  a region where **elongated trajectories** are stable, and where Coriolis forces still dominate. But if the source of the L4 or L5 is a **gas giant**, the potential well might be stronger than I imagined, up to the point of danger, yes.

Comment: @DavidW The way I read it, it was the tiny percentage of naturally occurring heavier gases (mainly nitrogen and oxygen, as the only other choices with high abundance) from Gold's atmosphere, after the hydrogen and helium had escaped.  Jupiter has a lot of oxygen -- it's just got around a thousand times more hydrogen.

Comment: @Alfred The entire Smoke Ring was at least marginally habitable, but the densest atmosphere was around the two "clumps" nearest the L4 and L5 points.  Get too far around from those, and the air got a little thin.

Comment: @ZeissIkon  To come back on L4/L5 dynamics, I have carefully read the Wiki page. They are **not** at a local gravity well. In fact they are even at a local gravity **hill**, but **Coriolis forces** maintain the stability of complicated trajectories. People who are able to navigate between various **open** trajectories using Coriolis forces without getting expelled at the other end of the ring should be able to navigate Coriolis forces near a L4 or L5 point to get in and out. I remember a "danger" of getting trapped there which is hard to believe.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Crossed posts. Again, the "very center" of the zone nearest the L4 and L5 point is not more dangerous than the remainder of that zone. Or maybe my memory of a special "danger of getting trapped in the potential well" is a false memory ?

Comment: @Alfred Even from a gas giant in a tight orbit around a neutron star, the "well" at L4/L5 isn't deep enough to be hazardous -- that's just where everything in the Smoke Ring is densest; trees closest together, air thickest, most water and solid material to be found.  Danger is in getting too far around the ring from there or too far inboard, outboard, port or starboard, with the air getting thinner, or being on the wrong half of a tree when that happens.

Comment: @ZeissIkon So was that a false memory ? It seemed to me the danger was to get too far **into the center**, where (as I think I remember) gravity was "normal", nor primarily Coriolis, a potential well.

Comment: @Alfred I skimmed both books, and I didn't notice anything about the L4/L5 locations being intrinsically dangerous the way being too far In or too far Out would be.  (Or too close to Gold.)  (Which, given the Admiralty, doesn't mean they're _safe_, but that's about people, not gravity.)

Comment: @DavidW Danger from **people** ! That's possible. I believe I really remember the trip close to the center of the L4 as dangerous, but it might well be because bad encounters could happen there, not  a problem of gravity. Gravity as the cause  could be a false memory, danger I am pretty sure.

Comment: "shaped like 2 hockey sticks taped butt-ends-together".   Perhaps comparing the shape to the Integral symbol might be more succinct, and also reveal the source of the title.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Considering I've used that description to _explain_ what an integral symbol looks like... :)  But you're right about the association to the title.  I will reformulate.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - beat me to it. I was just reading down the comments to see if someone had picked up on the obvious… that the shape of the trees is in the very title of the book ;)) **∫**